# Drawing line between dragged ImageButton in android

Tags: android, drawing, line, geometry, imagebutton

Im tring to drag an imageView (the 4 circles) and for every move event draw lines between the 4 **centers** of the imageButton.
But every time i drag them the lines are a little bit off the center.[image: this is how it looks when i do a little dragging]

closeLines is an array that contains the 4 imageButtons

```
private void drawLinesBetweenDots(ImageButton[] closeLines) {
        dotHeight=closeLines[0].getHeight()/2;
        dotWidth=closeLines[0].getWidth()/2;
        canvas.drawLine(closeLines[0].getX()+ dotHeight , closeLines[0].getY() + dotHeight, closeLines[1].getX() + dotHeight, closeLines[1].getY() + dotHeight, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(closeLines[0].getX()+ dotHeight , closeLines[0].getY() + dotHeight, closeLines[2].getX() + dotHeight, closeLines[2].getY() + dotHeight, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(closeLines[3].getX()+ dotHeight , closeLines[3].getY() + dotHeight, closeLines[1].getX() + dotHeight , closeLines[1].getY() + dotHeight, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(closeLines[3].getX()+ dotHeight , closeLines[3].getY() + dotHeight, closeLines[2].getX() + dotHeight , closeLines[2].getY() + dotHeight, paint);
        imageView.invalidate();
    }

 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId()== dot1.getId() || v.getId()== dot2.getId() || v.getId()== dot3.getId() || v.getId()== dot4.getId()) {
            if (startOrStop) {
                float currX, currY;
                int action = event.getAction();

                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mPrevX = event.getX();
                        mPrevY = event.getY();
                        isRect = false;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        currX=event.getRawX();
                        currY=event.getRawY();
                        /*ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
                        marginParams.setMargins((int) (currX - mPrevX), (int) (currY - mPrevY), 0, 0);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                        v.setX((int) (currX - mPrevX));
                        v.setY((int) (currY - mPrevY));
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                        closeLines = getCloseLines(v);
                        //canvas.drawLine((currX - mPrevX),(currY - mPrevY), closeLines[1].getX() + dotHeight, closeLines[1].getY() + dotHeight, paint);
                        drawLinesBetweenDots(closeLines);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                        closeLines = getCloseLines(v);
                        drawLinesBetweenDots(closeLines);
                        prevThreshold = null;
                        isRect = true;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

How do i make the lines go from the center of the circles?